# Informed badge already achieved, but badge is still being aimed.

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, users

So there is this user that I found on MSE who turns out was suggesting edits on my posts, and I went to check his profile, and wow.

[image]

It seems like he has achieved his 'Informed' badge but it is still on his badge aiming section. Has this bug occurred before?

Comment: In generally, it is best practice not to call out specific users on meta.  As the identity of the user in question is not relevant to this discussion, I have edited your image to focus on the part that is relevant.  I would also suggest that this question is more likely to get a good answer on Meta SE (rather than Math Meta).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sadly, I'm still suspended, so MSE Meta is the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally, we had a similar question earlier this month on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why is the 'Next badge', Curious, the same as the Newest badge in this profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357440/295232). I can repeat my answer verbatim:

That's [status-bydesign](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This is how that widget looks for the owner (except that this is a different badge):

[image]

Until they've made a choice for which badge to track next, they will be registered as tracking that particular badge. And [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/27340/glorfindel?tab=activity) is how their profile will look to others:

[image]